# What is the relationship between method of characteristics and separation of variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The method of characteristics for a partial differential equation such as

$$u_t + cu_x =0$$

Yields a solution $u(x,t) = f(x-ct)$.

On the other hand, separation of variables $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ tells us that the solution would be

$u(x,t) = e^{\lambda(x-ct)}$

I am a bit confused as to why the first method yields a "more general" solution that the second one. I recognize that I have not specified any initial or boundary conditions and wonder if this may be a reason why I am confused. What is the relationship between both methods and how could the solution of the separation of variables method be extended so that it allows a solution with any function $f(x-ct)$ instead of just the exponential function?

Comment: As you are solving a linear equation, you can add solutions to obtain another solution. Adding the solutions of the separation methods, we have $u(x,t) = \int\!F(\lambda)\,e^{i \lambda (x-ct)}\,d\lambda$. You observe that the function $f$ in the methods of characteristic is the Fourier transform of $F$.

Comment: Thank you Fabian. I know how to represent a piece-wise function as a Fourier series, but have not succeeded into relating $f(x-ct)$ to the Fourier transform of $F(\lambda)$. Could you elaborate more on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separation gives you one solution (and thus not the most general function). However, as the differential equation is linear, you can add different solutions to get another solution.

In your case, separation gives the solution 
$$u_\lambda(x,t) = e^{i \lambda (x-c t)};$$
here, I took the liberty to rename $\lambda \mapsto i \lambda$ with respect to the question.

Now, some very generic class of functions (e.g., $L^2$ which should be additionally sufficiently often differentiable) admit a Fourier representation
$$ f(x) = \int\!d\lambda\, e^{i \lambda x} F(\lambda)\tag{1}$$ 
with
$$ F(\lambda) = (2\pi)^{-1}\int\!dx \,e^{-i \lambda x} f(x).$$

So given a function $f(x)$, we can build the linear combination (of the solutions provided by the method of separation) 
$$ u(x,t) =  \int\!d\lambda\,  F(\lambda) u_\lambda(x,t)$$
which is again a solution of the differential equation. With property (1), we obtain
$$ u(x,t) = f(x-c t),$$
that is the solution obtained by the method of characteristic.

Comment: Thank you Fabian. I have been trying to learn about Fourier Transforms. This sounds silly, but I cannot see how to obtain $F(\lambda)$ and how to integrate the fourth expression, $f(x-ct) = \int F(\lambda) u_\lambda(x,t) d \lambda$. I have looked online and have not found a similar example. How can you integrate this function?

Comment: You obtain $F(\lambda)$ by the third displayed equation. Regarding the forth equation, you should simply insert the expression for $u_\lambda$ and then you will recognize equation (1).

Comment: For that I would need to specify a function $f(x)$ right? I can't just simply plug in a general $f(x)$, obtain $F(\lambda)$ through the third equation and from there obtain $f(x-ct)$ from the fourth expression, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The procedure works for any (specific) function. So it works for all functions $f(x)$. The hard part to prove is that the second and third equation are compatible in the sense that if you start with any $f(x)$, you can obtain an $F(\lambda)$ and then via (1) you get back to the $f(x)$. But that theorem is proven in any book about Fourier analysis.